Central limit theorem for standard deviation?
Central Limit Theorem:

Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ be independent and identically distributed random variables with mean $\mu$ and finite variance $\sigma^2$ (of any distribution).
Let $\bar{X}_n$ be their sample mean.

Then:
$$ \sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n - \mu) \xrightarrow{d} N(0,\sigma^2) $$
$$ \frac{\bar{X}_n - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} \xrightarrow{d} N(0,1) $$
Does a similar theorem exist for distribution of sample variance?
Ex:

Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ be independent and identically distributed random variables with mean $\mu$ and finite variance $\sigma^2$ (of any distribution).
Let $\bar{\sigma}_n$ be their sample variance.

Then:.... ????
I know Cochran Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%27s_theorem) about the sampling distribution of standard deviation follows Chi Square distribution if original sample is normal distributed ... but is there some similar result when $X$ has any distribution?

Does this answer your question?
